# When adding polynomial features, the issue of multicollinearity doesn't hold. Why?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, polynomial

In the regression model, sometimes to capture the non-linear relationship between dependent and independent variables, we use polynomial features. But in regression, if the two or more features are correlated with each other, then regression coefficients become unstable, and non-interpretable, Causing the standard error of the model unreliable. But such a problem doesn't occur when we use polynomial features. Why is this the case?

Comment: Do you mean *orthogonal* polynomial features?

Answer (score 4):

In a regression model

$$E[Y|x,z]=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2z$$
people often want to interpret $\alpha_1$ as some sort of effect of $x$ holding $z$ constant, or less ambitiously, a contrast for observations different in $x$ but the same in $z$.  We thus care about conditions under which those interpretations hold, and also under which
$$E[Y|x]=\beta_0+\beta_1x$$
has $\beta_1\approx\alpha_1$ and so on. We might also care about how the Fisher information for $\beta_1$ and $\alpha_1$ compare -- how much harder is the estimation because of collinearity.

For a model
$$E[Y|x]=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2$$
people don't usually want to talk about varying $x$ while holding $x^2$ constant, because that makes no sense.

So, the sorts of problematic statements people want to make about models with correlated predictors aren't a problem for polynomials because people are much less likely to want to make those statements.

As a separate issue, extreme collinearity, where the design matrix is nearly numerically singular, is as much or more of a problem for polynomials as for distinct predictors. It's just that it's pretty unusual now that everyone works in double precision and can lose ten digits of $\hat\alpha$ to rounding error without hardly noticing.

Comment: In addition to Thomas' excellent explanation, collinearity causes problems when you use a model for prediction in a new dataset when collinearities in the new dataset are different from those in the model fitting dataset.  Polynomial terms are equally collinear no matter which dataset you apply them to. Contrast that to fitting a model with total cholesterol and LDL cholesterol when predictions can be wild if the two cholesterols are not consistent with each other in a new sample.

Comment: @Frank Your first point is excellent.  However, I don't follow your assertion about "polynomial terms are equally collinear," because it seems to me that in one dataset they could be nearly collinear while in another dataset they could be orthogonal.  Consider, for instance, $x$ and $x^2$ in (a) $x$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and (b) $x$ uniformly distributed on $[-1,1].$ Am I misinterpreting your statement?

Comment: Nice point.  I should have added the caveat that the data support needs to be somewhat similar (marginal distribution).  In other cases not only the marginal distribution needs to be similar but also the multivariate distribution.  In the cholesterol example I've broken the correlation between LDL and total cholesterol in the new sample.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of your question seems arbitrary to me, and you give no source to back this assertion.  As far as I can see, there is no reason that the use of polynomial regression terms would remove instability in estimation due to multicollinearity.

Comment: It's instability that doesn't matter.  Predicted values will be completely unharmed by extreme mechanistic collinearity, even though individual parameter standard deviations can be very high.  People used to spend a lot of time using orthogonal polynomials but when matrix algebra got better inside software packages the need for this somewhat vanished.